# How do I measure the dimensions of a DOM node's content area with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to calculate the width and height of a DOM node such that it does not include Padding, Margin and Border widths, i.e; width and height of Content Area. Currently, I have tried clientWidth and clientHeight but the dimensions does not equate with actual DOM node. What is the best way to calculate dimension for content area?

Comment: I wonder aren't you asking for `scrollWidth`/`scrollHeight` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the calculation point of view what @jordan said to eliminate padding left and padding right from clientWidth will give the actual size of content area. But the problem is that you cannot get values of padding left and right through **elem.style.paddingLeft** and **elem.style.paddingRight** if the styles are set through external stylesheets.

Below is the way to get actual values of padding applied by browser on node after reading external stylesheets:

```
var node = document.getElementById("nodeid");

alert("Padding Left before computed style: " + node.style.paddingLeft);

var st = window.getComputedStyle(node);

alert("Padding Left after computed style: " + st.paddingLeft);
```

Note: If you have node style using **STYLE** attribute then elem.style.paddingLeft will work otherwise not!

Answer (score 0):

`clientWidth` and `clientHeight` are the best ways to do it, but you'll need to subtract padding.

So to get width, you might do `elem.clientWidth - elem.paddingLeft - elem.paddingRight`.

Here's some documentation on determining dimensions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: There is one problem, the padding, margins and borders are set using a style sheet and when I try to get their width through javascript it return empty. For example, node.style.paddingLeft returns "" I have checked the node paddingLeft in chrome dev tool and its shows 3px. How I can get this 3px from JavaScript?

Comment: When are you checking the width? You may need to wait until after the onload function has been called, so that the whole page is rendered.

Comment: Yes I am checking it after dom load is completed. Verified the same in console. When I type  node.style.paddingLeft it returns "". In your answer I can see there is no property like paddingLeft in elem it should be in elem.style.paddingLeft